# regular expression word not followed by space

Tags: regex

i have strings like this:

```
toddler shoes
+saint +louis +baby +kids +clothing
+omaha +white +onesies
+albuquerque+mother+of+bride+gowns
+anaheim+mother+ of+bride+gowns
```

i need to find the last two strings that has multiple word separated by'+' but no spaces, I've tried the following but it won't work

```
\\+\\w\\b(?! )
\\+\\w(?! )
\\+\\w+(?!\\s)
\\+\\w[^\\s]
(\\+(\\s)*\w)+
```

but they all returned the first two strings.

Comment: There is a space in the last string you show. A typo?

Comment: What language is this in? Java?

Comment: i run it in mongodb commandline

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to find any number of + and or \w with no spaces.  Your regex

```
\\+\\w[^\\s]
```

is closest to the mark, but you want to put an * in there, or else you are just finding one of those characters.

In testing using Perl regex, the following works:

```
[\+\w]*
```

The brackets tell it to capture either a + or a word character any number of times.

Comment: updated my examples above, this regex won't work on the first case 'toddler shoes',

Comment: So, now I'm confused as to what exactly you want to grab.  Are you looking for verb/noun combinations?  If so, your regex would probably be tens of thousands of lines long.  When I am trying to figure out a regular expression, I find it helpful to spend some time writing in plain English what exactly I am trying to find, and any exceptions.  That will also help in asking questions about it.